# selenium web driver - substitute for getEval

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium IDE has

storeEval | /\d*$/.exec(storedVars['myLocation']) | qid

Selenium webdriver code I am using:

String qid = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("/\d*$/.exec(storedVars['myLocation'])");

While executing the jUnit code I get an error. Is the above Javascript executor statement correct?

Error:

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: null (WARNING: The server did not provide any           stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 1.23 seconds
    Build info: version: '2.20.0', revision: '16008', time: '2012-02-27 19:03:59'
    System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:     '1.6.0_31'
    Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:123)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:438)
    at         org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
    at com.ui.tests.CreateNewTrait.testCreateNewTrait(CreateNewTrait.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)`

Thank you

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? And, is driver initialized?

Comment: Yes driver is initialized. The whole program runs fine until the JavaExecutor statement is executed.                                        For the above IDE statement I did export test case as webdriver (JUnit4). But the storeEval statement was not converted to JUnit statement. So I am trying to write code for the above storeEval command. Thanks.

Comment: I know. But what should the command do?

Comment: the command should select all last digits from the current page URL that is stored in myLocation variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript looks to be incorrect.  If all you want to do is to take out the last digits from the current page url then you should try getting the url using driver.getCurrentURL and use java pattern-matcher instead of using javscript executor.  In IDE there was no provision for doing string, mathematical or logical functions and hence javascript was used..but with webdriver or rc, you have java power with you :)
Hope it helps.